# Java: passing static variables to constructors?

Tags: java, constructor, static

I have a classA with a lot of static variables.

Does it make a difference if I access these variables in another classB in a static manner, i.e. by just calling ClassA.variable or if I'm passing these static variables to the constructor of the classB (and assign it to static variables in classB for later usage)? Which one would you use?

Comment: _I have a classA with a lot of static variables._ **Alarm bells.** If you want to write testable code then pass these `static` variables into the constructor. If you want to write maintainable code then remove as many `static` variables as possible. `static` is evil!

Comment: 2 people (including myself) already told you that using mutable static fields were bad design in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26201432/junit-initialization-of-static-fields). How many more do you need to believe it?

Comment: You don't pass *variables* on a call, you pass *values*.  It makes no difference where the values come from.

Comment: Thank you. So should I just remove all static variables and pass instead non static variables to the methods?

Comment: I'm assigning the values to the fields in the main method, so the fields must be static otherwise I get an compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicating many fields would be a bad idea because it complicates maintenance.

If these fields are genuinely variable, rather than constants, you now have identically named variables in two different classes. You would have to remember to update both copies of each value in all places in the code where you update either one of them.

Even if the fields are constants, duplicating them muddles their meaning and purpose. Ideally there should be only one place in the program where these values are defined, which should be the class that is most relevant and meaningful to what they do.

Another consideration is, how closely related are ClassA and ClassB? If the reason you want to pass these values as parameters is because ClassB might sometimes want to be used by a different class instead of ClassA, then it makes sense to pass parameters because you can't hardcode references to the original fields in ClassA. But if there are many such parameters, it is unwieldy. In that case, you can use a separate class to hold configuration state shared by the classes. ClassA (and classes like it) would create and initialize instances of the Configuration class, and pass it as a single parameter to ClassB. The Configuration class would be the only place where the many variables need to be declared and documented.

On the other hand, if your two classes are intended to be two inseparable pieces of the same application, so ClassB can always count on ClassA being there, then the indirection is not necessary. Then the question again becomes, do you really want to duplicate these fields in ClassB?

If all you actually want is to reduce typing `ClassA.` in front of things, use a static import at the top of ClassB:

```
import static packageName.ClassA.*; // imports all static members
import static packageName.ClassA.fieldX; // imports a specific thing selectively
```

Then you can refer to things simply as `field1`, rather than `ClassA.field1`. This usage is frowned upon as it can easily make it confusing to find where the variables are coming from, but it could be a win for clarity if there are a few variables being used *many* times.